# Unable to add custom field to view

Tags: 7, views, entities

I created a new content type called 'Newsletters' and created an image, text and link field.

I then created a view-block and when I try to insert my custom fields they do not show up in the fields list.  I checked my permissions of the modules and my folders so that should not be the problem and there are no errors in my logs.

It's a bit confusing.
Drupal 7.41
PHP 5.4.45
views 7.x-3.13

Any insight to why I can't insert my custom fields would be helpful.
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is for you custom field?

Comment: I don't understand your question?

Comment: What do you mean by custom field. What are the names of your custom fields?

Comment: your question is: "why I can't insert my custom fields?" but I see in the picture your *Newsletter Image Upload*, this is not your custom field?

Comment: they are in the image I posted.  Hopefully you can see them:

Newsletter Image Upload (image field)
Newsletter Link Field (link field)
Newsletter Description Text (text field)

Comment: I am able to create a custom field.  But I can not add them to my view-fields list.

When I click 'add' and select a field to be added, nothing shows up in the list.

Comment: It's bizarre I have the same modules version as you and I never saw something like this, try to add only one field and lets me know

Comment: Tried to add just one and nothing.  I am totally miffed.  lol   Never had this happen before.

Comment: What is odd is that I can add my custom field into an already existing content type within the theme that I am using.   Is there some kind of permissions section for custom content types?   I'm lost.  :(

Comment: just to test, make a fresh install, create your content type and try to make the view

Comment: Works fine on all other websites.    Have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Change your jQuery version for admin pages.

Comment: Tried that and nothing.  :(

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that the machine names for my custom content types can not be longer than 24 characters.  As soon I shortened the names they inserted into the view as normal.

It's odd that I have never had that kind of problem before.  But so it is...

Thank you for your efforts!!  It is REALLY appreciated!